# Magento 2 admin users: who did what

Tags: magento2, user-account

I have made a search on google but i didn't found a results.
Is there an extension that track user's actions, so we can know which user create an invoice

Comment: Magento provide the user role and permission for admin.

Comment: If you want to track the admin actions, then you need to implement any third party extension to do it.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i need to know which admin user who created or edited a giving order/invoice

Comment: You need to do that things using third party extension.

Comment: if you just want to know which user has created an invoice or edited an order I wouldn't recommend installing an extension you can create that functionality

Comment: @MohitRane not invoices only, there's other actions

Comment: @tarekfellah have you tested the extension in my answer? I already tested it, and they even mentioned that it’s 100% open source in its description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this free extension: https://github.com/kiwicommerce/magento2-admin-activity It's recommended to install via composer for it to work correctly.

You'll need to enable the extension and turn on modules as you need (e.g Order) in configuration, after that, you can see the action by going to `System > Admin Activity by KiwiCommerce > Admin Activity`.

I tested with creating invoice and it is able to do what you need. (magento ce 2.3)

[image]

Comment: I see that tacking actions feature is not free

Comment: What do you mean? The screenshot was taken by me and I can track admin actions after install the extension, for example creating invoices. Do you need anything else?

Comment: You changed the link in the answer?

Comment: I delete the old answer and post new one because I was afraid that you wouldn’t get the notification. Anyways, check the new one, I tested it and I think it’s ok.

Comment: Ok i will test it, and if it's ok i will accept the answer